# What is difference between CRYPT() and MD5()?

Tags: php, passwords, md5, crypt, cryptographic-hash-function

When we use CRYPT() method of any variable.

```
$test = 'password';

echo CRYPT($test);
```

**Result**

```
$1$g9s9ZdtF$sBBiBc4PdljOL4sDLx4CK.
```

When we use MD5() method of same variable.

`$test = 'password';`

`echo MD5($test);`

**Result**

`5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99`

Now, what is difference in both Answer?

Comment: They are simply two different hashing algorithms. Comparing the result is meaningless as they are not intended to give the same result.

Comment: CRYPT is for creating hashes and also salted them meaning that every time will generate a diferent hash and MD5 is simple hashing algorithm. __PS. MD5 is very unsafe today, use SHA256 OR SHA512__

Comment: Since you want to hash passwords, you should absolutely use the [password_hash()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [password_verify()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) functions. MD5 and SHA* should not be used to hash passwords, because they are way too fast and therefore can be brute-forced too easily.

Answer (score 0):

crypt() is a function that creates password hashes from plaintext and a (randomly generated or provided) salt value. It can use several underlaying hash algorithms like DES, MD5, Blowfish or SHA.

Using a "salted" password means that the same plaintext input does not always produce the same hash. So you can't say "I've seen this hash before it's the one for 'abc123'".

As it's available in libc there are crypt() functions in almost all programming languages and database servers so its very interoperable.
How secure it is only depends on the hash algorithm you chose (specified in as part of the hash).

For more information see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crypt_(C)